# Apache httpserver virtualhost not working

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost, httpserver

I have configured virtualhost in apache, conf contents below. (/etc/apache2/sites-available/myapp.xyz.conf). this is running on ubuntu 20.04.1

i have run "a2ensite myapp.xyz" successfully.

However, i cannot access myapp.xyz.net from browser. (We can’t connect to the server at myapp.xyz.net)

ping myapp.xyz.net in the machine works fine. but from external machine, it doesnt recognize myapp.xyz.net.

i have tried multiple suggestions but no luck.

I have updated /etc/hosts to include "127.0.0.1 myapp.xyz.net myapp.xyz.net" - no luck.

Tried changing <VirtualHost *:80> to <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80> and   - no luck

Appreciate suggestions.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapp.xyz.net
    ServerAlias myapp.xyz.net
   
   LogLevel warn
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/myappconsoleError.log 
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/myappAccess.log combined

    ProxyPass / http://myapp.xyz.net:8069/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://myapp.xyz.net:8069/
</VirtualHost>
```

Update:

I can access the page if i use http://1.2.3.4 . (1.2.3.4 is machine ip address).
What should my virtualhost config look like to access it by servername (i.e myapp.xyz.net)

Comment: When you say "_from external it doesn't recognize myapp.xyz.net_" what do you mean? Do you mean from another machine, or from a different application? Can you access `http://myapp.xyz.net:8069` directly (either in a web browser or via `wget` (both from the server **and** a remote machine)? Can you run `ping myapp.xyz.net` from a different machine? Have you checked the logs for anything relating to the host?

Comment: @DaveyBoy . by external , i mean from another machine. http://myapp.xyz.net:8069 , does not work either from external browser, with error of cannot find server myapp.xyz.net. However, when i try wget on the machine, it does work (although in try 2). --2021-06-30 16:43:45--  (try: 2)  http://myapp.xyz.net:8069/web/login
Connecting to myapp.xyz.net (myapp.xyz.net)|127.0.0.1|:8069... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4690 (4.6K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

Comment: when tried from external machine , windows curl 
>curl http://myapp.xyz.net:8069
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: myapp.xyz.net

Comment: If external machines are returning `Cannot resolve host`, you need to add a DNS entry into either your local host file, or the system wide DNS server.